# IOS Swift Google Maps truncate the title

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm adding markers with the titles to the map using below code.

```
func showAllMarker(){
        loadLocatons(){
            completion in
            if completion {
                super.hideLoading()
                self.mapView.clear()
                self.circle(withRadius: self.Defradius, circleCenter: self.myLocation2D)
                for point in self.mobLocationData {

                    if point.status == ConstantValues.activeStatus{
                        let marker = GMSMarker()
                        let latitude  = point.latitude
                        let longitude  = point.longitude
                        let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: NSString(string: latitude!).doubleValue, longitude: NSString(string: longitude!).doubleValue)

                        marker.position = position
                        marker.title = point.description

                        marker.userData = LocationMarkerData(id: point.id!, address: point.address!)
                        marker.map = self.mapView
                    }
                }                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2, execute: {
                    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: self.myLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.myLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 10.5,bearing: 350,viewingAngle: 10)
                    CATransaction.begin()
                    CATransaction.setValue(1.5, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
                    self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
                    CATransaction.commit()

                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Some times when tapped on the marker doesn't show the full title. It truncates the title. See below image.

[image]
In the google maps docs it says that only the very long messages may be truncated.

> Strings that are longer than the width of the info window are
>   automatically wrapped over several lines. Very long messages may be
>   truncated.

But the title of the above marker in the image is **"test"**. So it is not a very long title. Also there are some other markers which have more longer titles than this and they are not getting truncated. See below image

[image]

So could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong and how to correct this?

Comment: @udi try to add your text in marker.snippet = point.description this way

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Didn't work it

Comment: @ravi.p Snippet also got truncated

Comment: I don't think that the google map sdk truncates the title. It seems to be a problem with rendering (and appears only on specific devices and only with specific small titles). Sometimes the width of a UILabel is a little bit too low (1 pixel), so iOS truncates the text of the label and put three dots instead. Even I can't help you with a solution, perhaps there is the possibility to get the underlying UILabel and increase its width.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the first letter of your word Capital case like this:

```
let outlet_name = "\(DataDict["routeName"] ?? "")".lowercased()
marker.title = outlet_name.capitalizingFirstLetter()
```

This magically worked for me.